# Is it possible to add a photo's comments on facebook to my external webpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I found out that you can embed a post but I wonder if it is possible to include the likes and comments of an existing facebook photo on my external webpage?

Something like so
[image]
[image]

Comment: No, I tried to.. but You are not commenting on the picture but its link! so it's possible, try it you then publish the comment to Facebook the check Your timeline, You will see "XXXXXXX commented on a link" not a photo